# Radio button submission?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want the two uppermost radio buttons (top-left and top-right) below to change the html that's inside the red boundary (a div element). Each radio button represents a form for ordering a service (there's a submit button that's omitted from the screenshot), so the radio buttons are supposed to switch between html giving these ordering forms (if any doubt, I'm talking about real life services, like cleaning your house).

But the radio buttons' onserverchange event isn't raised before the form is submitted. Any ideas for how to force this particular part of the page to submit so that all the necessary code is executed? Without causing the actual service form to be submitted (because that submit button is tied to an email generating method).

[image]

I hope you understood me xD I find it tricky to talk about this because words like service, and form have dual meanings, one irl and one in code.

This is the html for the two buttons

```html
<label id="lbl_ftjenester" runat="server" style="color: black; background-color: #f2f2f2; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; float:left; border: 2px; padding: 5px; border-width: 4px; border-style: outset; border-color: #00e6ab;">
                Flyttetjenester<input id="ftjenester" type="radio" name="skjematype" runat="server"/></label>
            <label id="lbl_hleie" runat="server" style="color: black; background-color: #f2f2f2; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; float:right; border: 2px; padding: 5px; border-width: 4px; border-style: outset; border-color: #e6b800;">
                Hengerleie<input id="hleie" type="radio" onserverchange="change_input_form" name="skjematype" runat="server"/></label>
```

This is the event code:

```js
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    HtmlInputRadioButton v_ftjenester = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
    HtmlInputRadioButton v_hleie = new HtmlInputRadioButton();

    HtmlGenericControl v_lbl_ftjenester = new HtmlGenericControl();
    HtmlGenericControl v_lbl_hleie = new HtmlGenericControl();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //sets the status of the ordering forms in terms of looks and on/off
        v_ftjenester = ftjenester;

        ftjenester.Checked = true;

        v_lbl_hleie = lbl_hleie;

        v_lbl_hleie.Style.Add("opacity", "0.5");
    }

    protected void change_input_form(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //some css code to show change in status
        v_hleie = hleie;

        if (v_hleie.Checked == true)
        {
            v_lbl_hleie = lbl_hleie;

            v_lbl_hleie.Style.Remove("opacity");

            v_lbl_ftjenester = lbl_ftjenester;

            v_lbl_ftjenester.Style.Add("opacity", "0.5");
        }
        else
        {
            v_lbl_ftjenester = lbl_ftjenester;

            v_lbl_ftjenester.Style.Remove("opacity");
            
            v_lbl_hleie = lbl_hleie;

            v_lbl_hleie.Style.Add("opacity", "0.5");
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Remove the radio button on change event if it is associated. It would be great if you can share some code for the form and radio buttons within it.

Comment: I added some code. But the problem really isn't what the code is, but that I need some way for the onserverchange to cause a script to run without any regular submission buttons involved.